# How to show progress bar while reading multiple text files

Tags: c#, winforms

I am reading text files line by line from subfolders one by one. That means once it completes the reading of all the text files containing one subfolder then start reading files from the next subfolder. That you can understand from my code. Everything is working fine , what I want is to show a progress bar when it starts the reading from the very first file and then hide the progress bar when the execution finished. Any help can be appreciated. Below is my code :

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string newFileName1 = "";
            string newFileName2 = "";
            week = textBox2.Text;
            if (week == null || week == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Week cannot be null.");
                return;
            }


            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

                string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                string folderName = Path.GetFileName(folderPath);
                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

                foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    newFileName1 = "Files_with_dates_mismatching_the_respective_week_" + folder.Name + ".txt";
                    newFileName2 = "Files_with_wrong_date_format_" + folder.Name + ".txt";

                    if (File.Exists(folderPath + "/" + newFileName1))
                    {
                        File.Delete(folderPath + "/" + newFileName1);
                    }

                    if (File.Exists(folderPath + "/" + newFileName2))
                    {
                        File.Delete(folderPath + "/" + newFileName2);
                    }

                    FileInfo[] folderFiles = folder.GetFiles();

                    if (folderFiles.Length != 0)
                    {
                        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                        foreach (var file in folderFiles)
                        {
                            var task = ReadFile(file.FullName, folderPath, folder.Name, week);
                            tasks.Add(task);
                        }

                        Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
                        DateTime stoptime = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan totaltime = stoptime.Subtract(starttime);
                        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(totaltime);
                        textBox1.Text = folderPath;

                    }
                }
                DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Read the files successfully.", "Important message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task ReadFile(string file, string folderPath, string folderName, string week)
    {
        int LineCount = 0;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }

            string oline;
            while ((oline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                LineCount = ++LineCount;
                string[] eachLine = oline.Split(';');

                string date = eachLine[30].Substring(1).Substring(0, 10);

                DateTime dt;

                bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

                if (!valid)
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + "Files_with_wrong_date_format_" + folderName + ".txt", true);
                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(fileName + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Line number :" + " " + LineCount);
                    sw.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    int calculatedWeek = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.Localized).GetWeekOfYear(Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Saturday);

                    if (calculatedWeek == Convert.ToInt32(week))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + "Files_with_dates_mismatching_the_respective_week_" + folderName + ".txt", true);
                        await sw.WriteLineAsync(fileName + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Line number :" + " " + LineCount);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is impossible in such way becouse you don't know how much files you have before subfolders traversing. If you want to have realistic progress bar you have to travers subfolders and fill collection of files and then read the files.

Comment: side note: `Task.WhenAll` without `await` has no affect on the code, so I doubt *" Everything is working fine"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to show progress for each file itself or for all files in one?

You can get your file size with:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;
```

Set your progress bar minimum to 0 and maximum to 100.
Create a variable containing the current stream position and then update your progress bar with:

```
(int)(((decimal)currentStreamPosition / (decimal)fileLength)*(decimal)100);
```

You can either add all file sizes and show percentage or set the currentStreamPosition to zero when finished reading one file.

You have to traverse all files you need to read before getting the exact file size in sum.

Comment: I want it for all the files in one.

Comment: Then you have to add all file sizes while traversing and then set your currentStreamPosition variable to zero after reading one file.

Comment: and you should do this in a background worker and use update progress to show the changes in the ui, if not the ui thread will hang untill the process completes and the progress bar will not update

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in similar situations, it is better to show 2 progress bars if possible - one for Overall progress, another for Current. So, you can count all files in all SubFolders first to estimate Overall progress and then show reading of each file in Current progress bar.

If progress bar should be only one - than only Overall progress can be displayed.
You can count files number with Directory.GetFiles method. See following link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx